# Django group items by bucket

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a table bucket_items with columns bucket_id and item_id i want to group item_ids by bucket_id, using
`ItemBucket.objects.values('bucket_id', 'item_id')` this returns list of dictionary containing bucket_id and item_id, what i want is a list of dictionary with bucket id as key and list of item_ids as value something like

```
[{1: [1,2,3]}, {3: [7,3,2]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `values_list` will be better here instead of `values`, which returns `tuples` instead of `dicts`. So you can do something like

```
final_dict = dict()
for (bucket_id, item_id) in ItemBucket.objects.values_list('bucket_id', 'item_id'):
    final_dict.setdefault(bucket_id, []).append(item_id)
final_list = [{bucket_id: final_dict[bucket_id]} for bucket_id in final_dict]
```